# WPF Webbrowser Title and Script Errors

Tags: wpf, browser

I was hoping this was simple, I did search but apparently I'm blind.

How do I get the title of the current page I'm on.

I read that I could use wb.Document.Title but it says Title is not a valid option.

I just need it to see if it contains a certain word in it so I can raise an event if so.

Also, some of the pages that I have come across seem to have script errors in them. How do I suppress them so they do not show to the user? I tried wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true; but again, it didn't recognize ScriptErrors Suppressed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: this is what I found: webBrowser.Document.Title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way: webBrowser.Document.Title

Comment: Doesn't compile as described. If you really have found a simpler way to get the document title than @René's answer, I'd like to see it.

Comment: The only way this would work is if you're actually using the WinForms control, which provides more managed stuff, instead of the WPF version.

Answer (score 4):

To get the title of the doc:

1. Add a reference to "Microsoft HTML object library" (COM) to the project.
2. Cast the Document object to HTMLDocument:

   `mshtml.HTMLDocument dom = (mshtml.HTMLDocument) browser.Document;`
3. Now you can access the title property:

   `Messagebox.Show(dom.title);`

Comment: I found a better way:  webBrowser.Document.Title.